# SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, ssl, composer

При установке с помощью композера любых пакетов, выпадает ошибка

[image: tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed]

Пол дня убил, так и не нашел решение. Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: github.com в браузере открывается-то?

Comment: github.com открывается

Comment: npm нормально работает